# React Native Integration Exception: android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState on a null object reference

Tags: android, react-native, android-drawable, drawable

When I want to do RN integration with existing app, I encountered a npe problem that drawable object is null. The stack info is attached below. The problem seems made by TextInput component. Now, I do not know what to do to solve this problem.

I use react-native 0.70.10
react 18.1.0

[stack info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyn8s.png)
[debugger info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zIhV.png)

I tried to delete the codes related to  component and the program worked well. But I need this component to make the interaction complete.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.